# monaco editor with webpack 3 - unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel-loader, monaco-editor, webpack-3

I'm trying to use `monaco-editor` in my project that uses webpack v3 (I can't update it for the moment).
When trying to use it with `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin` I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object../node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/platform/keybinding/common/keybindingsRegistry.js
```

As far as I understand this is because webpack 3 does not compile node_modules and therefor I get an error on the `import {...}` line in `keybindingsRegistry.js`. I tried making webpack compile that code by making `babel-loader` test for the monaco folder and include that folder but nothing works.

How can I make `monaco-editor` work under `webpack 3`?

Comment: Share your webpack config code please